# How to create a table from a data.frame where a cell could have multiple values using R

Tags: r, dataframe, categories

I have tried looking at cheatsheets and looking over other questions asked on here but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.

I am using **R** and My data.frame looks like this:

[image: Data]

I want to take the second column and make it the vertical categories and make the third column the horizontal categories. The first column would then be matched to the corresponding categories in its row.

Here is an example of how I want to format the table:

[image: Table]

Is there a way write a code to do this in order to avoid using Excel and Word to create the table?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my question to show that I am using R. The dataframe is in R and I wish to make the table in R as well, instead of in Excel. I find the easiest why to explain what I am trying to do by the two pictures included. I want to make the second and third columns of the first image (Raw data) to create the categories of the table in the second image. The first column of the data would then be put into the table based on the Vertical and Horizontal values in its row. Thank you!

Comment: You  needed to update the tags so that R experts would see the question. I have now done that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = data.frame(let = LETTERS[1:12], 
                vert = c(10, 10, 2.5, 5, 10, 5, 2.5, 10, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25),
                hor = c(2,2,3,2,4,2,3,4,1,4,4,1), 
                stringsAsFactors = F)


# find unique combinations
positions = expand.grid(unique(df$vert), unique(df$hor))

# pre-allocate matrix
M = matrix(ncol = length(unique(df$hor)),
       nrow = length(unique(df$vert)))

rownames(M) <- sort(unique(df$vert))
colnames(M) <- sort(unique(df$hor))

# loop over valid positions and put them in the matrix
for (i in c(1:nrow(positions))){

  # get row
  row = as.numeric(positions[i,])

  # gather all entries that go in position
  valid = df[df$vert == row[1] & df$hor == row[2], 'let']
  valid = paste(valid, collapse=",")

  # get matrix indices
  vert_i  <- which(rownames(M) == row[1])
  horiz_i <- which(colnames(M) == row[2])

  # put the data in the matrix
  M[vert_i, horiz_i] <- valid
  }

print(M)
```

It could be more efficient but it gets the job done.

Comment: I got this one to work for my data, thank you! I see you used print(M) to visualize the new table, is there a way to view it as a plot?

Comment: You could use grid.table(M) (after call to library(grid)).  Or if you're using Rstudio, View(M)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# example data
exd <- data.frame(
    Vertical   = c(10,10,2.5,5,10,5,2.5,10,1.25,1.25,1.25, 1.25),
    Horizontal = c(2,2,3,2,4,2,3,4,1,4,4,1),
    row.names = LETTERS[1:12])

# move values into a column
exd <- mutate(exd,
              Value = rownames(exd))
# aggregate by Vertical and Horizontal
exd <- summarize(group_by(exd, Vertical, Horizontal),
                 Value = paste(Value, collapse = ","))
# re-arrange into the desired form
spread(exd, Horizontal, Value)
```